# Clash Royale Algorithm for troops path

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, weighted-graphs

I am making a clone of Clash Royale which is basically a Tower Defence game.

[image]

As you can see from the picture you can deploy different troops only in your side of the court (that blue rectangle), and they will automatically target the enemy tower (placed in the enemy court in red) or, if there is one, the enemy troop nearest to him.

P.S.: In order to cross your half court the troops can cross only over one of the two bridges (that orange rectangles) in the half.

Now I am trying to figure it out how do deployed troops find their path to enemies troops or towers from an algorithmic point of view. I initially thought of a weighted and directed graph $G = (V, E)$ in which each troop is a node $V$ linked to enemies thanks to an edge $E$ whose weight is the distance beetween the nodes it links... but now I think is more complex than it would appear as a first sight. Anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Most people, myself included, are probably not familiar with this game. Can you describe more clearly what sort of behaviour you're trying to model, and why you think your current attempt is insufficient? Thanks.

Comment: I modified the question giving a basic description of the game dynamics which im interested in

Comment: Note that your idea would make the implementation of collisions with buildings etc. harder to implement. The easiest method to achieve such behavior is putting a fine grid over your map and mark which cells are blocked. The $A^*$-Search Algo. can be used to find paths in such graphs.

Comment: What are the constraints on what paths troops are allowed to follow?  What are you trying to minimize?

Comment: @plshelp Interesting idea, thank you so much. Can you tell me if it's easily implmenetable even if troops are moving and so I need to update every frame their positions? Also i got some constraints on where troops can move as I mentioned in the question, i. e. they must cross only over the bridges marked in orange so how can I implement that behaviour by using a grid ? Thank you so much, really

Comment: @D.W. I think I have answered your question about constraints in the previous post. Let me know if I am not clear in my explaination. Thank you